# Wrong colors when loading textures in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures, glut

I'm trying to understand how to load a texture in OpenGL and I wrote this very simple code:

```
GLuint texture;

void loadTexture() {

    GLubyte data[] = {  255,0,0,
                        0,255,0,
                        0,255,0,
                        255,0,0    };

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);          

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

    int chk = gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 2, 2, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

    if (chk!=0) 
        printf("error code = %d\n",chk);
    else 
        printf("success\n");  

}
```

I use `loadTexture()` to load the texture in memory. The texture, in this sample, is extremely simple, but at the moment it doesn't matter.

```
void drawTexturedSquare() {

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f (10.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f (10, 10, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 10, 0.0);

    glEnd ();
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

I would like to apply this simple texture to a square. I call function `drawTexturedSquare()` from inside a `draw()` function where I already called

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

The problem is that this is the result I get

[image]

while I expected the square to be green in main diagonal (upper-left to lower-right) and red is secondary diagonal (upper-right to lower-left). May someone explain me why?

Besides, every time I run the program I get a different result:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

I do not understand where this blue comes out...May someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each row of your data needs to be 4-byte aligned. Either pad each row with 0 0, or use a RGBA texture.

If you don't want to do the aforementioned, you can use:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

The reason your color is changing is that since you don't pad your rows correctly, OpenGL reads past the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you please explain to me why, if I use RGBA texture, the code works fine even if I put 0 alpha? I would expect to "see" a transparent square...

Comment: You need to setup a blend mode that uses the alpha channel before it has any effect on rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `GL_NEAREST` for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`

As it is right now, OpenGL is interpolating between the colors, creating a gradient (since your texture is being stretched from 2x2 to however big your screen is)

This doesn't explain why you're getting different results for your texture each time though.